# Ambari Server fault tolerance

Tags: hdfs, ubuntu-14.04, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We have a 4 nodes Hortonwork HDP 2.3 cluster, managed by Ambari 2.1, up and running on Ubuntu 14.04. So far so good. We can run some jobs on Pig, Kafka, and Spark, etc. I'm just wondering: is there any way to make our system fault tolerance? E.g. in case if Ambari Server goes down, the whole cluster becomes unmanageable.

Is it possible to have some kind of 'Standby' Server to be able automatically detect that main Server goes down and that Standby Server able to pick up all jobs and services currently running and become a 'main' master Server without losing the jobs?!? It is not an issue with the slaves nodes, through Ambari UI we can easily manage hosts (add/delete) and see the current state of each of them. But question is what if Master node goes down.

We are new to HDP and unix world. After research I've made, I found only one article [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-7896) but the Status of article is 'Open' and the Resolution is 'Unresolved'. Does anyone in here faced same issues and can provide some solution or point me to the wright direction, or maybe it is still not supported and one of the 'coming soon' feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambari HA (High Availability) is not currently officially supported. A feature request has been made which you have linked to in your question. The fact that the ticket is still in the open, unresolved, and unassigned state means no one is actively working on this feature request at this moment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments cjackson, however, it is not a great news lol Will wait for this feature. Thanks for letting us know!